# Return all columns for a minimum value depending on a grouped column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm quite new to t-SQL and are having trouble with what I think is a quite basic query. I'm trying to return all my table columns for a minimum value (price) depending on the destination variable. My current query is:

```
SELECT min(price) as price, origin, destination FROM prices
GROUP BY origin, destination
ORDER BY destination
```

Which yields:

```
price               origin      destination
392                 Baltimore   Aarhus
264                 Kansas City Aarhus
...
```

However, I need it to be:

```
price               origin      destination
264                 Kansas City Aarhus
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What "destination variable"? Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` :

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, row_number () over (partition by product, destination order by price) as seq
      from prices p
     ) p
where p.seq = 1;
```

EDIT : You can use updatable cte for update operation  :

```
WITH U_CTE AS (
     SELECT lp.*, 
            row_number () over (partition by product, destination order by price) as seq
     FROM lowest_price lp
)
UPDATE ucte
      SET ucte.col = ucte.price
FROM U_CTE ucte
WHERE seq = 1;
```

Comment: In the case that I would want to add more grouping variables (e.g. product), how would the code above be aligned?

Comment: @random_user_567. .  Then add `Product` in partition clause.

Comment: If I wanted to incorporate the select statement above into a stored procedure that updates a table named 'lowest_price' using the values of the query. How would those additions look like?

Comment: @random_user_567. . . You should ask other question.

Comment: Fair enough - I have a solution for the above question, but I reckon it's not efficient/best practice. Unfortunately, I'm on "question cooldown" right now. Btw - thank you very much for the help

Comment: @random_user_567. . . That is not good practice so. Btw, i made changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can write sql as below

```
SELECT a2.mp, a1.origin, a2.destination
FROM A a1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT min(price) AS mp,
          destination
   FROM A
   GROUP BY destination) a2 ON a1.destination = a2.destination
AND a1.price = a2.mp
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1ca2ebd1063ae05e29eba227ae19792c)

Comment: In the case that I would want to add more grouping variables (e.g. product), how would the code above be aligned?

Comment: @random_user_567 You just have to add 'product' after destination in group by. Is this  answer work for you ?